# Fragment doesn't refresh content after returning from back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ZooFragment` which contains a `ViewPager`. 
This `ViewPager` has three children: `LionFragment`, `LeopardFragment`, and `TigerFragment`, each of these children can request transaction to call a new `ZooFragment`.

When a `ZooFragment` called `zooA` (with arguments) is initialized, all three children in `ViewPager` display content. From any child fragment, user touch will call a new `ZooFragment` called `zooB` (with different arguments, of course).

Based on transaction action from child fragment to `ZooFragment`:

1.If I use `transaction.replace()`, `zooB` will be blank, all three children in `zooB` display no content, empty. At `zooB`, pressing hardkey `Back` from navigation, `zooA` becomes empty.

2.If I use `transaction.add()`, `zooB` won't be blank, following by a `Back` button press, `zooA` gets empty.

In `ZooFragment` class, I do loading data in `onCreateView()`, so what is the reason why all the child fragments in `ViewPager` get empty?

Comment: You left out the most important part: where do you do make the transaction with the new `zooB` fragment?

Comment: @Luksprog by touching to a `View` in one of the children fragments, for example, `LionFragment`, transaction to `zooB` goes from here.

Comment: I wasn't clear in th previous comment, I'm more interested about the container where you put `zooB`.

Comment: It's just a `FrameLayout`, where at least one `ZooFragment` exists.

Comment: I think the problem is due to an incorrect use `FragmentManager`(or the wrong one) or problems with the containers. Some code about those transactions would be helpful.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the FragmentManager. If you are using a ViewPager inside of a ZooFragment, you should be using `getChildFragmentManager()` for handling Fragments inside the ViewPager since you are dealing with nested Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not replace the fragments in the ViewPager, just show (using transaction) in any other contained in the same layout as that of ViewPager and that container should be a FrameLayout. Also device a mechanism to know when and what fragment comes into view. Then request for a fresh data from a utility that responds to update your fragment. I do not think onDestroyed will be called in case of all the fragments in the ViewPager.
Fragments in the ViewPager are fixed, so should there contents will not go till the application manager wants to destroy it.Instead of trying to replace the fragments in the adapter, try to give a different set of fragments and notifyDataSet changed, or take the advantage of FrameLayout to show another fragment over the view pager tab's current fragment.

There is my solution that works:

[Swipe Gesture applied at Fragment level along with ViewPager with it's default swipe disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821775/swipe-gesture-applied-at-fragment-level-along-with-viewpager-with-its-default-s/19020100#19020100)