# back button handling in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have two fragments [1] and [2]. In fragment[1] I have asyncTask. when I am on the [2] fragment and  press back I want to go back to fragment[1] and refresh it automatically. 
Please give me a hint how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your fragment to the backstack! Once you do that you should be able to go 'back' to it. For example:

```
FragmentManagerfragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransactionfragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
myFrag=newMyFrag();
myFragList.add(myFrag);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFrame,myFrag);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("myFrag"); //Important line
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: yeah for going back and displaying fragment [1], but I want to refresh it plus.

Comment: This might be of some use :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607580/fragment-doesnt-refresh-content-after-returning-from-back-stack